# Submanifold in $R^n$ with positive sectional curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, submanifold

I’m trying to prove that for a compact hypersurface $M⊂R^n$($n>2$),there exists a point p where $sec(σ)>0$ for all 2-planes $σ ⊂T_pM$.
My idea is :
Since M is compact, we can choose a maximal point p of distance function $r(x)=d(0,x)$ on $M$ and try to show $sec_p>0$.
By Gauss equation, it suffices to show the 2nd fundamental form is positive definite at p, and I only know that 2nd fundamental form  equals to Hess$r$ when the hypersurface $⊂r^{-1}(a)$. But how can Hessian make sense here? Is there any other method to deal with it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: HINT:  Think about curvature at $p$ of curves in $M$.

Comment: I prefer a graph over a hyperplane to a radial graph, so here's my preferred approach: Pick a unit vector $u$ and find the hyperplane normal to $u$ furthest from the origin that intersects $M$. $M$ therefore lies to one side of the hyperplane and the hyperplane is tangent to $M$ at any point of intersection. Now move the hyperplane so that a point of intersection is the origin, the tangent plane is $x^n = 0$, and $M$ lies above $x^n=0$. $M$ near the origin is now a graph $x^n = f(x^1, \dots, x^{n-1})$, where $f$ has a local minimum at the origin. You can do the rest.

Comment: @TedShifrin If we choose a geodesic in $M$ starting from p, then the 2nd fundamental form will equal to the signed Euclidean curvature(greater than circle’s curvature at p). And by Gauss equation, the sectional curvature is positive. Is that how it’s done?

Comment: Sounds good to me.